# Are there any performance benefits to gRPC compared to JSON over HTTP/2 other than size?

Tags: performance, grpc, http2

I read that gRPC is more performant than traditional HTTP APIs due to more compact serializing with Protocol Buffers. The other performance claim is that unlike HTTP/1.1 JSON APIs, it supports pipelining.

As I currently understand, the pipelining of multiple connections over a single HTTP connection is done by HTTP/2 and not by gRPC. So, apart from the from the more efficient data serializing format, is there actually a performance benefit for gRPC compared to JSON over HTTP/2?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple aspects here.

### Protocol: HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2

There are many improvements in HTTP/2 over HTTP/1.1, but there are also disadvantages for some use cases. Some examples of improvments:

- HTTP/2 is a binary protocol whereas HTTP/1.1 is a text protocol
- HTTP/2 can reuse the TCP-connection for multiple requests sent to different endpoints but to the same server.
- HTTP/2 has improved header compression features with [HPACK](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/). This is useful if you e.g. send the same `Authorization: Bearer <JWT-token>` in consecutive API-requests.

### Payload format: JSON vs Protocol Buffers

This may have an effect on payload **size** but **serialization and deserialization** performance is probably more important. Another important aspect is developer tooling and productivity.

Protocol Buffers, used by gRPC is **not** the only efficient binary payload format. There are many alternatives, e.g. [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/), a zero-copy format, designed after experience with Protocol Buffers. Another binary format, mainly for smaller payload (not serialization performance) is [Avro](https://www.confluent.io/blog/avro-kafka-data/). Avro format may have a benefit in evolvability of the payload format (see e.g. [Designing Data-Intensive Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321)).

See e.g. [JSON vs Protocol Buffers vs FlatBuffers](https://codeburst.io/json-vs-protocol-buffers-vs-flatbuffers-a4247f8bda6f)
 for a comparison.

### gRPC

gRPC is a higher protocol abstraction than purely using HTTP/2. Fewer details is left to the developer to take care of. In all, there are many aspects in the choice of HTTP/2+JSON vs gRPC, it all depends on what's the most important aspect for your use case.